# how to get certain sql results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i'm looking to get certain sql results from a query depending on where they are positioned, for example, consider this code

```
SELECT * FROM Product ORDER BY id asc
```

which could return at least 100 or so results.

the question is though, how can i get the first 1 - 10 results of that, and then in another **different, separate** query, how can i get the results that are 11 - 20 or even get the results that are positioned 51 - 60 of that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways, here's one approach using [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```
DECLARE @StartRow INTEGER = 11
DECLARE @EndRow INTEGER = 20

;WITH Data AS
(
    SELECT TOP(@EndRow) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RowNo, *
    FROM Product     
)

SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE RowNo BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow
ORDER BY Id
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE to get the row number and then query by the row column

```
with your_query as(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS Row, *
   FROM Product 
)
select * from your_query
where Row >=5 and Row<=10
```